# Sticky footer with transparent background

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky

It's possible to achieve sticky footer with transparent background without content background(.wrapper) under it?

I'm using -> http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/layout.css

Answer (score 0):

It is simple CSS trick:

```
#footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Position: fixed actually tell that contents must not move while scrolling.
When position is fixed, we need to give exact position, which is done by bottom: 0.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uDqbE/)

However contents will go under it and visible with transparent background. One way of making contants not visible under it is, wrap contents in a wrapper with position fixed, with top, left, right :0 and bottom : 'height of your footer'